# How many positive integers with exactly four digits have at least two 3's?

Tags: combinatorics

Tried doing this by finding all integers with no 3's, and all with one 3 and then subtracting these from the total number of integers, but ended up completely off. Every way I try to do it comes up with completely different answers that don't seem right.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Think of in how many different ways you can place two occurrences of the digit 3 in a 4-digit integer. The other digits can be anything: a special case is that of the most significant digit *not* being the digit 3, since here the digit 0 cannot appear.

Answer (score 0):

I would place exactly two 3s in the four digit number first and consider those to be the leftmost 3s in the number.  Therefore, any digit to the right of the 2nd three could be anything and any unknown digit to the left of the 2nd three could be anything except a three (with he exception noted above that the first digit could not be a 0.  This approach prevents double counting the ones with three or four 3s.

There are six possible placements of two 3s with the following count of possible 4 digit integers:

33xx : 10 * 10 = 100

3x3x : 9 * 10 = 90

3xx3 : 9 * 9 = 81

x33x : 8 * 10 = 80

x3x3 : 8 * 9 = 72

xx33 : 8 * 9 = 72

Total is 495

It would also be possible to do this with inclusion/exclusion but more work.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers with no 3's: 8*9*9*9 = 5832

Numbers with one 3: As the first digit: 9*9*9 = 729, as another digit: 8*9*9*3 = 1944.

Total: 5382 + 729 + 1944 = 8505

All 4-digit numbers: 9*10*10*10 = 9000

Difference is 9000 - 8505 = 495.